# Liquibase get active contexts in custom change

Tags: liquibase

I need to write a custom change that has some tweeks depending on which profile is active. Is there a way to get the active contexts in an implementation of `CustomTaskChange`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The maven profile?

Comment: No, the liquibase contexts.

Comment: So your question is: How can one access the context inside the `CustomTaskChange`?

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for.